# How to access IConfiguration in test script

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller in my MVC asp.net core app.

Inside this app I am using DP to access the appsettings.json file:

```
public class APIServicesController : Controller
{
    IConfiguration _iconfiguration;
    public APIServicesController(IConfiguration iconfiguration)
    {
        _iconfiguration = iconfiguration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var Key = _iconfiguration.GetSection("EMAIL_API").GetSection("Key").Value;
        var uri = _iconfiguration.GetSection("EMAIL_API").GetSection("uri").Value;
        var emailAddress = "an email address";

        var res = _api.ValidateEmail(emailAddress, Key , uri );
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a test script for this. How do I access/use the IConfiguration from my test script?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ValidateEmail()
    {
        var emailAddress = "an email address";

        var res = await _api.ValidateEmail(emailAddress, key, uri);
        Assert.AreEqual(res, true);
    }
```

Comment: What object mocking library are you using as a part of unit testing?

Comment: @R.Richards Hi thanks for posting.  Normally i would use nsubstitute but I could not get it to work with .Net Core so not using any :(

Comment: Ouch! Doing it the hard way. :) I was going to suggest mocking it, but... Have you considered Moq? I works for me in my Core projects.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson You could use pure DI to stub the dependency and inject that into the system under test. Show how you arrange the api for test. The current provided example is incomplete. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @R.Richards I shall lok at MoQ. Thanks

Comment: @Nkosi all this is pretty new to me. Could you post an example?  thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson, Actually for what you are trying to test it does not look like you need access to IConfiguration. The method under test just needs to be provided with input. But again there is not enough context provided in the current state of the question.

Comment: @Nkosi Well I wanted to test getting the setting form the json file too you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this in an integration test class:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var config = builder.Build();
```

Add this nuget package: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Now that you have the config file, you can get what you need:

```
config.GetSection("whateverSection");
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to build the memory completely within the test:

```
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                       .AddInMemoryCollection()
                                       .Build();
        configuration["SomeKey"] = "some value";
```